# What is the best way to solve a system of linear equations that have the same constant term of 1

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this system of linear equations.

*2x<sub>1</sub> - 4x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>3</sub> = 1*

*x<sub>1</sub> - 3x<sub>2</sub> + x<sub>3</sub> = 1*

*3x<sub>1</sub> - 5x<sub>2</sub> - 3x<sub>3</sub> = 1*

What is the best way or is there any special way to solve this sort of system?

Comment: Your equations will look better (and will actually be much easier to write) if you use MathJax. For example, if you type `$x_1$` we will see $x_1$. You can start learning about it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending @fleabloods answer, there are several methods, mostly standard... I'm sure there are better answers of this question out there, but cannot find any at this moment in time.

Now, your equations are:

\begin{align}
2 x_1 - 4x_2 - x_3 = 1\\
x_1 - 3x_2 + x_3 = 1 \\
3x_1 -5x_2 -3x_3 = 1
\end{align}

> Variable elimination

This goes by several names, but this is the one I use. First, you pick a variable, say $x_3$, and you eliminate it from your equations.

If we call your equations `[1]`, `[2]`, and `[3]`, then we notice that `[1]+[2]` is  $3x_1 - 7x_2 = 2$. Any other mixture of equations will get you that same equation. Notice we can go from the old equations to the first equation and our new one. Thus we have reduced our system of equations to:

\begin{align}
2 x_1 - 4x_2 - x_3 = 1\\
3x_1 - 7x_2 =  2\\
\end{align}

Which, we can go on to find solutions for still, but the solutions will be infinite.

If we now erase $x_1$, then we can go by `3*[1']-2[2']` which is $2x_2 -3x_3 = -1$.

From this point, we can now find our infinite set of solutions. Let $a=x_1$ be the first component of a solution. Then the coefficient of $x_2$ is $\frac{3a-2}{7}$, and from there, our coefficient of $x_3$ is $\frac{2x_2+1}{3} = \frac{2a+1}{7}$. Or more beautifully: $\frac17(7a, 3a-2, 2a+1)$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$ are solutions.

> Matrix calculation

by looking at the matrix, we can see that it has rank 2 so is not-invertible (i.e. the infinite solutions as above), and by finding the null space, we can find all the vectors which would be solutions by performing row and column reduction (which translates into rearranging the equations earlier). Finding row reduced upper echelon form should take you the last step above.

Comment: if $a=3$, then we get the solution $(3, 1, 1)$, which I see you found!

Answer (score 0):

There a several ways.  All the usual ways.  Why are you expecting a "special" way?

You can do:

1) $2x_1 -4x_2 - x_3 = x_1 -3x_2 + x_3$

$x_1 = x_2 + 2x_3$

2) $2x_1 -4x_2 - x_3=3x_1 -5x_2 -3x_3$

$x_2+2x_3 =x_1$ (redundant)

3)$x_1 -3x_2 + x_3=3x_1 -5x_2 -3x_3$

$2x_2+4x^3= 2x_1$

$x_2 +2x^3 = x_1$  Still redundent!

That looks slick but ....  it actually *isn't*.

You *lose* the information.

Just do it your normal way.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: The answer is (3, 1, 1) but i don't know how to figure it out

Comment: Oh... I assumed you already knew how to solve linear equations and were asking if there was a special way to do it for the special case when equations are equal to the same constant rather than different constants.  There isn't really.  You do it the same way as you would if the equations were equal to different constants.  Which I assumed you already knew.  mdave16 does a very good job showing how to do those.

Comment: Hmm.... I did make an error somewhere though.....

Comment: Ah... a sign error.... oops.